# Suppose that $x, y, z$ are three positive numbers that satisfy the equation $xyz=1, x+\frac{1}{z}=5$ and $y+\frac{1}{x}=29$.

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

> Suppose that $x, y, z$ are three positive numbers that satisfy the equation $xyz=1, x+\frac{1}{z}=5$ and $y+\frac{1}{x}=29$. Then $z+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{m}{n}$, where $m$ and $n$ are coprime. Find $m+n+1$.

I tried this, $$y=29-\frac{1}{x}$$ $$y=\frac{29x-1}{x}$$
And, $$x+\frac{1}{z}=5$$ $$z=\frac{1}{5-x}$$

What can I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just substitute the values of $y$ and $z$ in $xyz=1$.
$$\frac{x(29x-1)}{x(5-x)}=1$$
$$29x-1=5-x$$
$$x=\frac{1}{5}$$
$$y=\frac{29/5-1}{1/5}=24$$
$$z=\frac{1}{5-1/5}=\frac{5}{24}$$
$$z+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{5}{24}+\frac{1}{24}=\frac{1}{4}$$
Thus, $$m+n+1=1+4+1=6$$

Comment: What? $xyz=\frac{29x-1}{5-x}$!

Comment: @Nightflight What do you mean?

Comment: You wrote $$\frac{x(29-x)}{x(5-x)}=1$$

Comment: @Nightflight So what is wrong? Can you plz point it out?

Comment: Do you think there exists real number $x$ satisfies $29-x=5-x$? Really?

Comment: @Nightflight Oh! Sorry, typing mistake I will rectify immediately. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution: we have $\frac{1}{x}=yz$, $\frac{1}{y}=xz$, and $\frac{1}{z}=xy$. So

\begin{align*}
x+xy&=5\\
y+yz&=29\\
z+xz&=Q
\end{align*}

where Q is the quantity we're trying to determine.

Multiplying these three equations together gives $145Q=xyz(x+1)(y+1)(z+1)$ and hence $145Q=(x+1)(y+1)(z+1)$.

Expanding, we have

\begin{align*}
(x+1)(y+1)(z+1)&=xyz+xy+yz+xz+x+y+z+1\\
&=2+xy+yz+xz+x+y+z\\
&=2+5+29+Q\\
&=36+Q
\end{align*}

and so $145Q=36+Q$, from which it follows that $Q=\frac{1}{4}$.